# Firebase storage rules works on playground but throws 403 from client

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

1. This is my firestore database:

*brokers* collection:
[image]

*companies* collection:
[image]

*users* collection:
[image]

2. These are my firebase storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
     
    function getDocument(collection, documentId) {
      return firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/$(collection)/$(documentId));
    }
    
    function getUser() {
      return getDocument('users', request.auth.uid).__name__;
    }
    
    function userIsMember(collection, documentId) {
      return getUser() in getDocument(collection, documentId).data.get('members', []);
    }
    
    match /companies/{companyId}/contracts/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if userIsMember("brokers", getDocument("companies", companyId).data.broker[4]);
    }
  }
}
```

3. My problem:

Whenever the user *vJIwuxn4jXN88Hs5uv3fZXcTlyu1* wants to get the downloadURL with the following code:

```
const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(
  ref(
    storage,
    "companies/company-id/contracts/contract-id/document.pdf"
  )
);
```

he gets a 403 error but I don't understand why as I believe the rules should allow him to read the file.
[image]

The weird thing is that if I try to debug the rules within the playground it works:
[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you show all related data here: the relevant documents in Firestore and the code you use to access Storage.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior based on the information and steps you provide. We also need to see some debugging information that shows the user's UID is exactly what you expect, and that it matches the relevant documents in the database. What you show right now doesn't show actual, working data.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I have edited my original question. Is this enough information for you ?

Comment: What is this supposed to return? `getDocument("companies", companyId).data.broker[4]`.  What is that thing that looks like an array index?

Comment: Also your broker members array is storing a path to a user, not a UID. That doesn't look right.

Comment: `getDocument("companies", companyId).data.broker` is a reference towards the brokers collection. So calling `[4]` will get me the broker document id. In my case `broker-id`.
Information was found here: https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/QPHV3JpQR7M/m/lgeWnGhHBwAJ

Comment: The members array is an array of references towards the users collection because every time a new user is added in the auth module, it creates a document in the users collection with the same UID.